# How I can delete the lines that contain " + "?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to delete the lines which containing + .
I tried some codes but my effort wasn't successful.

Before:

> DET NOUN . PRON CONJ NOUN ADP PRON VERB PRT VERB ADP NOUN . DET VERB VERB . ADP CONJ PRON PRON VERB VERB NOUN ADP NOUN VERB .
>
> ADV VERB PRON PRT ADP NOUN . ADP DET NOUN . PRON CONJ NOUN ADV VERB . DET N+N . PRON CONJ NOUN VERB ADV ADP NOUN . CONJ NOUN VERB DET .
>
> CONJ NOUN VERB DET NOUN .
>
> CONJ PRON ADV ADP NOUN VERB . VERB DET ADJ+ADJ+N DET VERB DET ADJ ADJ+N .
>
> CONJ PRON CONJ NOUN PRON VERB VERB .
>
> CONJ PRON VERB . ADV ADP VERB PRON PRON VERB . Q+N VERB ADP PRON VERB . CONJ PRON VERB PRON ADV ADP PRON NOUN VERB .
>
> PRON VERB NOUN DET ADJ NOUN .

After:

> DET NOUN . PRON CONJ NOUN ADP PRON VERB PRT VERB ADP NOUN . DET VERB VERB . ADP CONJ PRON PRON VERB VERB NOUN ADP NOUN VERB .
>
> CONJ NOUN VERB DET NOUN .
>
> CONJ PRON CONJ NOUN PRON VERB VERB .
>
> PRON VERB NOUN DET ADJ NOUN .

Which regex I should use in Notepad++ to delete the unwanted lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^.*\+.*$` should do the trick.

What it means:

`^` means "start of line"

`$` means "end of line"

`.` means "any character"

`*` means "previous element, zero or more times".

So, it reads:

Line start, any characters, a plus sign, any characters, line end.